# After I compile opencv_contrib to opencv3.1,I still can't use SURF

Tags: python, opencv

Below is my cmake options:

> cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_EIGEN=ON -D BUILD_DOCS=ON -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuarithm=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpubgsegm=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpucodec=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpufeatures2d=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpufilters=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuimgproc=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpulegacy=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuoptflow=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpustereo=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuwarping=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/include/python3.5m -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libpython3.5m.so ../../opencv-3.1.0

I just type:

```
import cv2
cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)
```

then a error happened:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

What are the possile reasons lead to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are using opencv3.1 ? What does `print cv2.__version__` returns?

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak I'm sure about that I'm using version3.1,and the output is '3.1.0' after i execute "cv2.__version__" in console.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with contrib? I don't see that in the make file

Comment: @Miki you got me,It's my mistake,ORZ.